# ML model to predict CPU utilization of a server given x amount of tasks

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, lstm, cross-validation

I have comprehensive data points of what the CPU utilization of a server is when x amount of jobs are running, let's say the server is using 40% CPU util time=x and there are 4 jobs running.

The tricky part I am trying to figure out is that, the few time intervals before and after time=x can have an impact on the CPU utilization.

In the end all I want to figure out is how much CPU will be used when x number of jobs are running.

I have tried multiple regression and rnn models with no success, I think the tricky part is that the time before and after can have a big effect, for example util can be 90% when there are 0 jobs, because right before it there was 20 jobs, etc.

Comment: Are the data points timestamped?

Comment: @liakoyras yes the datapoints are timestamped